# Python if statement list comprehension

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, list-comprehension

```
word = ['cat', 'dog' ,'rabbit']
s = []
s = [ l for w in word for l in w if s.count(l)==0 ] 
print s
```

This code is giving me output
['c', 'a', 't', 'd', 'o', 'g', 'r', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'i', 't']

I don't want any redundant elements in the list. Could anyone please tell what am I doing wrong. I want to know why if statement is not working ?
Is there any other way to do it with List comprehension so that I don't have to define a s named list initially.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want unique letters, how about using a set?

```
>>> word = ['cat', 'dog' ,'rabbit']
>>> set().union(*word)
set(['a', 'c', 'b', 'd', 'g', 'i', 'o', 'r', 't'])
```

---

If you want to preserve order, I guess you could do

```
letters = "".join(word)
s = [letter for idx, letter in enumerate(letters) if letters.index(letter) == idx]
```

Or, if it's absolutely necessary to do it in one line

```
s = (lambda letters: [letter for idx, letter in enumerate(letters) if letters.index(letter) == idx])("".join(word))
```

But both of these are O(N^2) so they're impractical for long lists.

Comment: set will unfortunately not preserve the order, which may be important

Comment: Could you please explain me your code "set().union(*word)" . What does *word do ? I mean how does his create another set ? Could you please me you other code as well ?

Comment: @AnuraagGupta: `*args` in a function call tells the Python interpreter that `args` is a list or tuple of arguments and to unpack the `args` list / tuple to extract those arguments. So in this case `union(*word)` has the same effect as `union('cat', 'dog','rabbit')`. It's mentioned in the tutorial in [Unpacking Argument Lists](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists). When used like this the asterisk `*` is often called the splat operator.

Answer (score 4):

You define `s` as an empty list. That doesn't change until it is reasssigned to the *result* of the list comprehension; which can't happen until the comprehension itself has executed. So, at the point where the code is inside the comprehension, `s` is still empty, so `s.count(whatever)` is always 0.

Comment: So, what is alternative to solve this problem when I only to want to use List comprehension ?

Answer (score 3):

Daniel Roseman has explained why your list comprehension doesn't do what you want. But your logic works fine if you use traditional `for` loops:

```
word = ['cat', 'dog' ,'rabbit']
s = []
for w in word:
    for l in w:
        if l not in s:
            s.append(l)
print s
```

**output**

```
['c', 'a', 't', 'd', 'o', 'g', 'r', 'b', 'i']
```

List comprehensions are *slightly* more efficient at appending to a list than using `.append()` in `for` loops like this because they use a special  LIST_APPEND bytecode, which saves on making a method call, but usually the speed difference is marginal.

Comment: I want to solve this only using List comprehension. Could you help.

Comment: @AnuraagGupta: _Why_ do you only want to use a list comprehension? List comprehensions aren't magic, and they aren't really suitable for this task. Kevin's second example does most of the work in a list comp, and it _could_ be modified to do all the work in a list comp, but that would be wasteful since it would have to re-compute `"".join(word)` for every character in `word`. Another strategy would involve doing `append` in a list comp, which would create a list full of `None` which is then discarded. I hope that it's obvious that that's also a wasteful algorithm.

Comment: FWIW, the last strategy I mentioned above looks like this: `s = []; [s.append(c) for w in word for c in w if c not in s]`. But ***PLEASE*** do not do this in a real program!

Comment: Thank you @PM 2Ring. It was a question in the book I was reading. I thought that I should try and learn if I can do it using list comprehension. But I get it that its not magic and I'll try finding better ways to code.

Comment: Fair enough. It's good to explore these things. BTW, you should [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) one of the answers here, so that the system knows that your question has been answered to your satisfaction.

Answer (score 0):

The if statement is working but you need to update `s` if there is a non-redundant element `l`. Just append `l` to `s`.

```
word = ['cat', 'dog' ,'rabbit']
s = []
[s.append(l) for w in word for l in w if s.count(l)==0]
print s
```

Output

```
['c', 'a', 't', 'd', 'o', 'g', 'r', 'b', 'i']
```